# NetLogo Headless Meaning with respect to speed

Tags: netlogo

What does one exactly mean by headless mode of NetLogo? I am considering it is running netlogo without GUI, what about the speed of slider for the model running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`netlogo-headless` doesn't need to deal with speed slider ... the speed slider is there only to manage the computer video ressource. Without GUI the speed is maximum.